# State array is not getting updated

Tags: django, reactjs, api

In this react class State, Users array is not getting updated? but,
updated service data is  displayed on console log.In ComponetDidMount() using customersService to hit api and fetching the response data,
then updating state

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CustomersService from './projectservice';
const customersService = new CustomersService();

class ProjectDeatil extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { users: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const { match: { params } } = this.props;
      if(params && params.pk) {
        customersService.getCustomer(params.pk).then((user)=>{
          console.log( user);
          this.refs.title.value = user.title;
          this.refs.description.value = user.description;
          this.refs.image.value = user.image;
          this.refs.link.value = user.link;
          this.refs.body.value = user.body;
          this.refs.language.value = user.language;
          this.refs.slink.value = user.slink;

          this.setState({users: user.data});
        });
      }
    }

  render() {
    const{ users } = this.state;

    return (
      <div >
        <div className="row e text-white">
        {/* // {this.state.users.map( users => */}
          <h1 className="card-text text-white" key={users.pk}>Hello { users.pk}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }  
}
export default ProjectDeatil
```

Please Guide Me To solve this problem

Comment: Hi Rajul, can you please add a bit more detail of what you're trying to do as it's not very clear at the moment

Comment: Thanks Timmy  , I Solved My problem And got result